# Is there any way to use t2.small EC2 instance when deploying Datomic Transactor to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, clojure, datomic

I'm able to deploy *Datomic Transactor* using *Datomic Auto Deploy Scripts* to EC2(**c3.large**) instance and it works really well but I would like to use **t2.small** because it's cheaper.

When I try to change instance type from **c3.large** to **t2.small** from CF template file I get mapping error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a way to look at your CF template?

Comment: When I change instance type I get an error.It can't find the type of that instance.

Comment: You're going to have to show this CF template for better help. Alternatively, are you on an account that supports Classic EC2 networking? Do all `t2` instances not work? Or `c4`? Or `m4`?

Comment: I got it working on tc2.nano instance but it does not work, I assume the reason is different storage system. It's Java processor and it should be working on any EC2 instance IMO.

Comment: Datomic Transactor defaults to a 1 GB heap in development mode (and I think 4 GB in production mode). `t2.nano` instances only provide 512 MB total, so you're likely running into a problem of the JVM not being able to allocate enough heap on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it turned out in CloudFormation.json file did not have **t2.small** instance type:

```
...
"Mappings":
 {"AWSInstanceType2Arch":
 {"m3.large":{"Arch":"64h"},
  "c3.large":{"Arch":"64h"},
  "hs1.8xlarge":{"Arch":"64h"},
  "i2.xlarge":{"Arch":"64h"},
  "t2.small":{"Arch":"64h"},
...
```

And I added **t2.small** in there.Then changed the following part:

```
...
 "Parameters":
 {"InstanceType":
  {"Description":"Type of EC2 instance to launch",
   "Type":"String",
   "Default":"t2.small"},
...
```

Also I needed to change JVM heap size parameters like this(1.5GB):

```
...
  "Xmx":
  {"Description":"Xmx setting for the JVM",
   "Type":"String",
   "AllowedPattern":"\\d+[GgMm]",
   "Default":"1500m"},
...
```

Since **t2.small** has 2GB RAM it's okay to set to 1500M.

So everything worked as expected...

Comment: It would be awesome if you could expand this answer, with a complete set of steps that you took...

Comment: I think it's all there what kind of additional info you need ?

Comment: How did you get the .json file in the first place? Is it always named `CloudFormation.json`? Once you add `t2.small` to the json file, does it need to match up with settings elsewhere? Basically, steps to reproduce... The answer is okay, but someone coming to it with less experience deploying a CloudConfiguration, might be confused...

Comment: Yeah, I can share the datomic video that explains the steps so datomic has scritpts that create those files for you and I made some changes one of those files.Would it be helpful?

Comment: I think so. Maybe, with some explanation at what stage your intervention, and alternate set of steps fit in. Thanks for figuring this out btw.

Comment: This actually isn't working for me. When I deploy the cloud formation, it starts, but then immediately the status eventually shows "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" in the AWS Cloud Formation dashboard.

Comment: Your ensured-trans.properties is correct and you were able to run a transactor on aws with different instance type before?

Comment: Can you show how you use the "Xmx" parameter inside the CloudFormation file?

Comment: @uldall if you use latest datomic it allows you to use t2.small they updated CloudFormation file